# How to get my blog on Planet Drupal

Tags: community-official-site

## Background

- I have started a [tech blog](https://jigarius.com/blog) which will regularly have Drupal articles.
- I've followed the [Planet Drupal instructions](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/content/planet-drupal) specified on Drupal.org

  - Created an RSS feed and validated it on W3C validator
  - Ensured that it has 2 original initial articles
  - Created a [ticket](https://www.drupal.org/project/content/issues/3052075) to request the addition of my site to Drupal Planet

I've also contacted a Planet Drupal maintainer, i.e. people who approve Planet Drupal feeds.

## The problem

It's been around a week, but there's no news :( I believe that my articles will get stale and they won't be picked up by the weekly drop.

Is there anything I can do to accelerate the process? Or is there something I'm not doing right?

Comment: In the past, I've read several of your articles hosted on diff website. I enjoy reading them, they are very well written and I learned useful info.